# RoR Deployment - Development Windows/Productiv Linux possible?

Tags: linux, windows, deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

i am just started learning RoR following a book/tutorial (http://ruby-auf-schienen.de/3.2/webserver_mit_capistrano.html). I reached a chapter about setting up Capistrano Deployment. nginx with unicorn is used in the tutorial. My enviroment is Windows 7 PC for development and Debian PC as production server The problem is, that unicorn will not work in the Windows enviroment because ngio error after *bundle install*:

***Installing kgio (2.8.0)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension***

Searching here and other sources i found that this error is because kgio is for *nix systems only.

My question now is, can i setup my enviroment the way with capistrano deployment using unicorn/nginx for production and thin/nginx for development? 
When yes how? 
When no, what is possible without changinging the development PC to Linux?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Unicorn will never work on Windows because it's explicitly designed around Unix technologies, while Thin doesn't. It's fairly straightforward. On Windows, `gem install thin`. If you run `rails s thin` it'll start Thin for you as the development server.

Having said that, I would generally discourage Windows as a development environment for Ruby work. There are a lot of gems that don't work properly on Windows, and your app is going to behave slightly differently on Windows than on Unix. At the mininum, you should have a staging server that runs Linux.

I would also recommend [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) over Unicorn. It's easier to use and to administer and is a very popular choice. For example it's used by New York Times, Symantec, AirBnB, Amazon, etc. It manages resources in a smarter way and has more stability and fault-tolerance features.